# Differences between Vue.component and new Vue?

Tags: vue.js

Please tell me what are the differences between Vue.component and new Vue.

1. The second parameter of the Vue.component method ( the [options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options) object ), is the same first parameter of new Vue constructor. right?
2. Are there any differences between two methods, in meaning and parameter options?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's introduce both of them first and we'll talk about the difference after it.

**What is New Vue?**

using `new Vue` we create a new vue *instance*; Every Vue application starts by creating a new Vue instance with the Vue function like following:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  // you'r options here
})
```

According to official docs(this [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)):

> A Vue application consists of a root Vue instance created with new Vue, optionally organized into a tree of nested, ***reusable components***.

now that we know what vue instance is let's take a look at [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

**What is Vue.component?**

Components are reusable Vue instances with a name and we can use them as custom elements inside a root Vue instance

**What are the differences?**

1. Since components are reusable Vue instances, they accept the same options as new Vue, such as data, computed, watch, methods, and lifecycle hooks. The only exceptions are a few root-specific options like el.
2. A root Vue instance is a Vue application launcher, Vue component is an extension of the Vue instance.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318536/differences-between-vue-instance-and-vue-component) post for additional info.

Comment: @itbestdevelopment Yes, the same except for root-specific options like el.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `new Vue()`, you're creating what is called a **vue instance**. A Vue instance **basically** is a JavaScript object that has some capabilities to interact with the DOM.

Vue components happen to be Vue instances, too. But the main difference is that components belong to other components/vue instances, while bare instances are mounted directly into an existing element of the DOM (with existing, I mean HTML that is not generated by Vue and existed previously to the instance creation).

So, basically, the main difference comes from the use: you **usually** create a bare Vue instance with `new Vue` when you need to attach that instance directly to the DOM as your **root element**. Vue components, on the other hand, are always attached to ** other components**.

In general, it is really common to have **a single root vue instance** in your Vue application, but you could have several bare instances in the same web page: you *could* get creative and span several Vue instances and make them interact with the DOM at the same time, as if they were components.

However, it is better to have a single root element with several components, since it is easier to reason about your code in that way, and also facilitates the use of plugins like Vuex or Vue-router.

Maybe [this link about this matter can serve you as well](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-relation-or-difference-between-vue-instance-and-vue-component-instance/12439).

Comment: The second parameter of the  Vue.component  method ( the  [options](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options) object ), is the same as first parameter of new Vue constructor. right?

Comment: yes, they are pretty much the same but I don't think components use the `el` field, since their mounting spot is managed by the parent. Also, in components, `data` must be a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Therefore, in new Vue constructor  [data option](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) is an object or a function, instead in Vue.component method the [data option](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data) is a function.right?